# Load Multiple Urls as One Page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Not 100% sure how but I know its simple .htaccess but I have no idea what to do.

Basically I want it to load a index.php file no matter what url they go to in the folder containing the index.php for example:
http://website.com/folder/thisisntafile.php will load: index.php in the folder named folder. This will happen for whatever /folder/file.php is loaded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite "folder/file"
#don't rewrite "folder/index.php"
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/[^.]+(\.php|html)?$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/index.php [NC,L]
```

This rewrites

```
 http://example.com/foo/bar.php
```

to

```
 http://example.com/foo/index.php
```

Comment: I understand this isnt just simple redirection right?

Comment: Working perfect, Just added a bit of modification removing /%1/ and /([^/]+) as I have the htaccess in the specific folder I called games.

Just one thing how do I make it so it changes for example: http://si.te/folder/file/ to http://si.te/folder/index.php (Of course make sure the last / isnt needed as its just a trailing slash).

Comment: Sorry, i had added a wrong path to the last rule. see the edit

Comment: The last rule isnt the issue its the last condition.

Comment: Its checking for /folder/file".php/html" not just /folder/file

Comment: Do you mean **folder/file** without extensions?  in a  comment above you said you  want to rewrite "example.com/file.php" to "example.com/folder/index.php" if that is the case then it should work.

Comment: Yes no extensions. Incorrect I said for example: si.te/folder/file to si.te/folder/index.php

Comment: I removed the wrong rules and updated regex pattern in second condition, php and html are optional now.